# running a word macro dynamically through java/html/jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

new to running macros through coding . Please help me if it is possible to do it through either of html/jsp/java...

Answer (score 0):

Using the Word object model you can trigger macros. I don't know that the operating system will allow that to happen from a web page though. Macros have access to a lot more of the computer (file i/o and other restricted resources for example) than web pages are allowed. Macros also usually require explicit user permission to run (depending on user settings of course).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague and ambiguous, but I guess that you initially want to execute the macro at the client machine (at the enduser's machine, there where the webbrowser runs). Otherwise this functional requirement makes totally no sense.

Well, JSP runs at the server machine (there where the webserver runs), not at the client machine (there where the webbrowser runs). So you can't do anything with JSP. All JSP basically does is generating some HTML output and sending it to the client machine. Your best bet is using a Java Applet or something like that (Flash? Flex? Silverlight? No idea what could execute a macro). Once you've finished programming that, just embed it in the JSP page appropriately that it ends up correctly in the generated HTML output.